# How to check if this combination exists in the array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm creating a product with combination of variation, and I'm having a problem with duplicate attributes but different sku.

I have an array like this

```php
$variations = [
  "PRODUCT-SKU-1" => [
    ["option" => "color", "term": "black"],
    ["option" => "size", "term": "small"],
  ],
  "PRODUCT-SKU-2" => [
    ["option" => "color", "term": "white"],
    ["option" => "size", "term": "small"],
  ]
];
```

and now I'm trying to find a way to avoid duplicate with same attributes. ex of an input array

```php
$newVariant = [
  "sku" => "PRODUCT-SKU-3",
  "attributes" => [
    ["option" => "color", "term": "white"],
    ["option" => "size", "term": "small"]
  ]
]
```

so basically this `$newVariant` variable has the same attributes with `PRODUCT-SKU-2`

Edited:

so basically I want to check if the two attributes combination already exist in the `$variations`

Comment: So basically remove all elements with same attributes? What is your original input structure? First one or second one?

Comment: @vivek_23 I want to check(return a bool) if this $newVariant['attributes'] already exist in the ```$variations```

Comment: It's a basic in_array check. https://3v4l.org/JZ7sP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare 2 array with == operator. It compares if all keys and values are the same:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

You could also use in_array() to check if array of array contains child array.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
if (in_array($newVariant, $variations){
// contains!
}
```